# Will upgrading a machine from Windows 7 Pro to 8 Pro remove it from a domain?

Tags: windows-8, active-directory

I have a laptop running Windows 7 pro SP1 x64.
It is on the domain at work.
If I do an in-place upgrade to Windows 8 Pro, will the resulting OS still be on the domain?

Answer (score 4):

It certainly shouldn't. I am fairly confident that it wont be removed from the domain.

Comment: I should try to validate that answer with: I have upgraded machines from Vista to 7 and they didn't need to be re-joined to the domain.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this exact upgrade on my work PC and it worked flawlessly.

I realize this is pretty much the same as the other answer but while his is theoretical my is based on 1st hand experience ;)